# "Click to Reveal Image" - Buzzfeed inspired feature

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, frontend, backend

how do I create an option where the user could upload a picture and the picture can be "clicked to reveal " or not. Does it require back-end for the image to have such option.

Please refer to this link for what it looks like.

Answer (score 2):

To upload a file you need the backend. Some good libraries for fileupload in Rails are [Refile](https://github.com/refile/refile), [Carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) and [Paperclip.](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)

For the blur effect you have to add some css to the image, something like this:

```
.blurred {
  filter: blur(5px);
   -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
   -moz-filter: blur(5px);
   -o-filter: blur(5px);
   -ms-filter: blur(5px);
}
```

Then you have to handle the clickevent with Javascript or jQuery to remove the filter.

Comment: I already have it , but  what I meant is , for the user to select an option whether the picture is to be blurred or not . What is your best recommendation for the option.

Comment: @Purry to have this option as user's choice best way is to handle it in `back-end`